# Add DIV after every 5 comment in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, comments

Is there any why to hook into wp_list_comments or something to add custom DIV with after every 5 comment in Wordpress?
I know I can modify comment data or comment template but I need to get something that hook into whole comments template.

Answer (score 0):

i had done similar things in my [naturopath blog](https://dein-heilpraktiker.com). You need to find the while-loop what is getting the comments from your db. you simply add a counter in it, like we learned in first lesson of php, and add an if-clause to the while-loop.

```
i = 0;
while (your-while-loop){
  i = i+1;
  the rest of the loop
  if (i = 4){
    echo "<div>YOUR AD</div>";
    i = 0;
  }
}
```

It's not perfectly well written, but i think you should get, what i mean. Comments, as well as posts are taken by while loops in wordpress. When you add a counter and if-clause to the loop, you can hook into a specific number or put something in between.

Comment: I know how to do classic loop and insert something after 4 element. But I have problem with hook into existing comments loop.

Comment: i edit my answer. have a look

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do it with jQuery.

First, make your div in a place that renders with your comments. You can do this modifying the template or making a plugin just for this. It is not important where in your pages it is showing, because it will be moved. Giv it a class, eg. youradd

In a js file (you can use the same DIY plugin for this. Remember to load de js file) write something like this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){  
    jQuery('.youradd').insertAfter(jQuery('li:nth-child(3n+3)'));
});
```

where youradd is the class of the div you just created and li:nth-child(3n+3) is... every 3 li element